# iOS Facebook SDK startWithGraphPath:parameters post to just SOME friends programmatically

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In Facebook, you can post something and share it with just *some* friends.
How can this be done programmatically on iOS using Facebook SDK?

My App has an "Emergency Button" that sends: a) User Location on a Map (picture); b) An emergency text (message); and c) The post is only shared with the friends the user has chosen in the config. section (privacy).

```
- (void)sendMessage {
 //Just an Example: Send an Emergency Post with: message, picture, just to SOME friends.
 //This action may not need the User to actually press a button.

 //Privacy parameter obtained from:
 //https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/post/

 NSMutableDictionary *privacy = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 @"100000278095294,100000278095528", @"allow", //Friends Id separeted with commas.
                                 @"", @"deny",
                                 @"CUSTOM", @"value",         //Privacy Custom Value
                                 nil];

NSMutableDictionary* params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[params setObject:self.emergencyText          forKey:@"message"];
[params setObject:self.locationMap            forKey:@"picture"];
[params setObject:privacy                     forKey:@"privacy"];

[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/feed"
                             parameters:params
                             HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error) {
                          if (error) {
                              NSLog(@"Error");
                              NSLog(@"Error descriptcion %@",error.description);
                          }else{
                              NSLog(@"Success");
                          }
}];
```

}

This code in not running. I get an error from Facebook.
If I comment this line:

```
// [params setObject:privacy forKey:@"privacy"];
```

Then it runs fine and I see the post in FB, but it is a *public* post.

I need to post: message, picture, just to *some* friends.

Any solution using `startWithGraphPath` or using any other command is welcome!

Comment: According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/feed privacy should only have 3 keys which is value, allow and deny. You seem to have a bunch of others. You are using the documentation for reading when you should use the documentation for writing

Comment: I take those parameters from official Facebook documents:    https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/post   I will try your solution for feed instead of post. Will let you know.

Comment: I changed it as you suggest, using only: allow, deny, value. But still not working. If I comment the line  // [params setObject:privacy forKey:@"privacy"]; it works fine, the comment is there, but everyone can see it. How can I set privacy for just 2 or 3 friends?

Comment: What does your code look like now?

Comment: I have changed my code in the original question so it reflects the parameters I'm using now, they are just: allow, deny, value. Still not working. if I comment the line //// [params setObject:privacy forKey:@"privacy"]; it works fine but everyone can see the post. If I uncomment that line I get an error: 

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170249120'

How can I set privacy for just 2 or 3 friends?

Comment: That looks like it should work for me. Please file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs so someone here can look into it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must format the privacy as a JSON string and then assign that json string to the params NSMutableDictionary.

For Example:

```
NSMutableDictionary *privacy = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             @"100000278095294,100000278095528", @"allow", //Friends Id      separeted with commas.
                             @"", @"deny",
                             @"CUSTOM", @"value",         //Privacy Custom Value
                             nil];
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:privacy
                                                   options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                     error:&error];

NSString *jsonString;

if (! jsonData) {
    NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", error2);
} else {
    jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}

NSMutableDictionary* params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[params setObject:@"to my friend"          forKey:@"message"];
[params setObject:self.locationMap               forKey:@"picture"];
[params setObject:jsonString                     forKey:@"privacy"];
```

Comment: i tried this. the post is successful, but i still don't see as a public post (it is still private). what else could be the issue (especially considering i get no errors on the post request)?